# Do we need all font-family files to make a font work?

Tags: css, fonts

So I have a font pack for example Font-Awesome.
They provide me with different file types like ***eot,*** ***woff,*** ***woff2,*** or  ***svg***. Now as per what I've read, We just need a single file for a specific font weight to work.

All I want to ask is, If we just add a single font file where font-weight isn't applicable, like Font-Awesome or Simple Line icons, what are the issues that we end up facing?

Answer (score 1):

[WOFF2 has nearly universal support right now](https://caniuse.com/woff2), so you don't need to include the rest unless you want to get those last few percentage points of users who are on older browsers.